# Подключение к WebSocket в цикле используя разные параметры С#

Tags: c#, websocket

Приветствую всех. Кто-нить может подсказать как реализовать следующую задачу.

Есть несколько наборов из урлов и куков. Каждые из них используются для подключения к вебсокетам.

Задача. Окрыть конект к каждому набору в цикле. Для работы с сокетами использую библиотеку WebSocket4Net.

Собственно для подключения к 1му сокету используется простая констукция WebSocket MyName = new WebSocket(url, cookie);

Дело в том, что я не могу вручную прописать открытие сокетов для каждого набора, потому что они берутся из бд и я никогда не знаю сколько их и с какими параметрами.

Поэтому нужно открывать их в цикле. При этом нужно открыть их таким образом, чтобы была возможность управлять каждым потоком с сокетами по отдельности. Т.е. у каждого должно быть уникальное имя MyName, насколько я понимаю.

Кто-нить сталкивался с такой задачей? Как ее лучше решить?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebSocket> sockets = new List<WebSocket>();
for ( ... )
{
  sockets.Add(new WebSocket(url, cookie));
}

sockets[0].Abort();
```

Comment: А обращаться к ним как потом? Какое имя каждый поток получит?

Comment: @Cергей - `sockets[...]`